# Parse error code 1 internal error when attempting to run a job

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have the following job I've created to clean out unneeded records. I've simplified the code below to troubleshoot the root cause, but with just this, over 80% of the times I run it fails to find anything due to Error code 1 "internal error":

```
Parse.Cloud.job('cleanStories', function(request, status) {

  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
  var counter = 0;

  var query = new Parse.Query('Story');
  query.doesNotExist("username");
  query.limit(1000);

  query.find({
    success: function(results) {
      counter += results.length;
      status.success(counter + " stories found.");
    },
    error: function(error) {
      status.error(counter + " stories found. Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
  });
});
```

I currently have about 568k records. This is down from almost 800k, which is when I started running this job to clean out records. It was usually running fine, but since has started erroring out very consistently. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I have decreased the limit to 50 and it has a higher rate of success on executing. At 100 (default) it still regularly fails. Is there anyway I can get it back up to 1000 to get through the rest of the records faster?

Comment: An "internal error" usually means just that - an internal bug - you should probably file a bug report.

Comment: Does it help to reduce the limit to something small?  It might just be that combination of record size and visiting 1000 to determine doesnotexist is causing you to exceed some max request time for jobs.  Smaller limit and cursoring through could help.

Comment: Updated the post with answers. @danh, how would I go about cursoring to get the limit back up to 1000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is based on a weak theory that smaller limits will help (if it really is a timeout issue, hopefully its a per query timeout and not a per job timeout, otherwise this idea won't help at all).  But here's an idea how to do large find using limit/skip:

```
function findN(query, results) {
    results = results || [];
    query.skip(results.length);
    return query.find().then(function(findResults) {
        results = results.concat(findResults);
        return (findResults.length === 0)? results : findN(query, results);
    });
}

// to run this, build a query 
var query = new Parse.Query("MyClass");
// qualify the query however you wish
// set any limit up to 1000, but our guess is that yours should be small
query.limit(20);
var results = [];
findN(query, results).then(function(r) {
    console.log("found " + r.length + " rows");
    // r will contain all of the rows matching the query, found 20 at a time
});
```

Comment: Marking as solved by @danh. It didn't exactly solve my problem, but got me to an ideal solution. I reached a point where I was lowering my query limit until I reached 1, and it would still fail. I then set the skip to 1 and was able to up it back to 1000, so I believe there's a record in the query results that was causing problems. I'm now using a variant of danh's code to batch through multiple sets of records to delete more than 1000 records in a single job run.